# Simple issue tracker for GitHub (Github bugtracker is not OK)

Tags: github, issue-tracker

I'm one of 1-3 (depending on how you count) software people in a small non-profit. I need a decent issue tracker. All of the code is stored on GitHub (although I'm looking for an excuse to move to Mercurial and Bitbucket …). We've been using the issue tracker that comes with GitHub, but it's really weak.

Currently, different parts of the organization use Basecamp, Asana, and Trello for project management. I figure it would be easiest to convince the users to use a bug tracker if it integrates with what they already use. (Also, if the bug tracker uses one of these, I can probably convince them to standardize on one project management system.)

I've done some googleing, and see that all three at least CLAIM that they have GitHub integration, but I don't know how good it is, or how good it will work as a bug tracker.

Does anyone have experience? Or another option?

Comment: It is unclear what you want - what kind of features are missing fom github bugtracker for you?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the founder & CEO of Comb

Comb <strike>is</strike> *was* an issue tracker that focuses on prioritization. Tasks are ordered in priority order and the system ensures that team members work on tasks in that priority order.

We aren't integrated (yet) out of the box to Basecamp, Asana, or Trello, but we do allow you to set up an integration to systems like these through custom buttons and webhooks that send data back and forth between Comb and the external system.

Comb was designed to be flexible in your workflow, so it could conceivably replace Asana and Trello for you (depending on how the other parts of the org feel)

Comment: link links to a hackerish site that claims """ *Click "Allow"   if you are not   a robot*

""". Great one, first I've seen that.

Comment: Yeah, the product died and the domain has since been grabbed by someone else :)